# How to setup Shared Google Calendar Notifications upon Event Creation

Tags: google-calendar, if-this-then-that

I have a shared Google calendar that myself and one other person adds events to.

Currently I use IFTTT to get an email each time an event is added. However this catches every event and does not say who created it.

Is there any way to only get notified when the other person adds an event rather than all events?

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the ingredients for IFTTT's Google Calendar "Add New Event" trigger includes the person creating the event. You might want to reach out to IFTTT and suggest it as an enhancement.